# Accessing the same variable from multiple classes

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a class that contains some variables.Let's name it "Var" class. In "Var" class i have some variables like int width ,int height and so on. Some classes need this variables in order to work, also this variables are changing. My problem is, when i am creating an object of "Var" class in diffrent classes , each object contains its own int width and int height, and i dont want that.So, how to access variables from "Var" class from multiple classes?

Comment: make them public and static, that way all the classes can access them, and there is only one width/height for the entire program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy solution would be to use the **static** modifier on the width and height variables to create only a single copy of the variables that belong to the class.

An alternative would be to create a single immutable reference to Var and **compose** other classes of the Var reference. This would **encapsulate** the fields of the Var class as well.

```java
class Var {

    private final int width;

    private final int height;

    public Var(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

}
```

Then you can have some class that depends on Var.

```java
public class DependsOnVar {

    private final Var var;

    public DependsOnVar(Var var) {
        this.var = var;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        int varWidth = var.getWidth();

        int varHeight = var.getHeight();

        // do something
    }

}
```